# Avoid recursive event in c#

Tags: c#, recursion

Hi I 've a little question, 
I'm using socket and I find many situation of infinite recursion see source: http://pastebin.com/Cbd2Z2uE

the problem is this:

```
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    ....
    // receive again
    socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer,
        0,
        StateObject.BufferSize,
        0,
        ReceiveCallback,
    state);

    ....
}
```

So we have an async function that is called again in a recursive way. Here We have a problem with the stack? 
To be more clear, this situation is ok and recursion is fine, the problem and question is:
in this case can I have a problem of stackoverflow?

thanks

Comment: I havent look at your situation, but when facing recursion, often the solution is to somehow stop recursion (stop condition) . Or in situation like a calls b and b calls a. Then introduce a thrid component c when the shared logic is.

Comment: thanks but is not the problem of recursion here, the question is in this "common" situation using socket I risk a stackoverflow or not, and if yes how avoid it :)

Comment: This is no different from any situation involving recursion - you have some condition, that if true, calls the recursion, and if false, it doesn't.

Comment: I suggest not using `BeginReceive` but instead creating a thread for each socket that will block and wait on `Receive`.

Comment: Looks like you're not recurring at all, you're chaining async calls (call -> callback, new call -> callback ...), so there should be no overflow issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not recursing (or in danger or recursing). You are simply scheduling a callback to be executed when an IO competion port receives data for you to process (checked source code to see this). This will not happen while your function is running on the current thread because the very same thread has to check for message on IO port via polling or another worker thread will run your function all together. In either case you are not recursing or in danger of recusing so the stack will not blow up (`socket.BeginReceive` should return immediatly & will not call your function in it).

I believe you are looking at [scenario 14 shown on this page](http://www.madwizard.org/programming/tutorials/netcpp/5) but it may be the previous scenario since your console app has a message pump. But the bottom line is that there is no actual functions recursing in your application (or supporitng OS framework functionality used by it).

Comment: So if I well understand: if I have an event or a call to simple Action I'm recursing in this case not, right?

Comment: Your situation is what you may call 'calling event handler', so in case of events usually (if done right) you are not recursing. Action is a high level abstraction over function pointers (delegates as known C#) so I'll not comment on that even though it has some relevance. But to recurse you have to call the same function within itself, so to create a recursion in you example: if you in (inside) the body of the `ReceiveCallback` method  call it again like this  `ReceiveCallback(null)` you will see recursion

Answer (score 2):

Your `ReceiveCallback` is called by framework code unless you call it directly.
`BeginReceive` stores specified delegate as callback function, and it doesn't calls the delegate at that time.

For example, I added some codes to get stack trace:

```cs
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.StackTrace);
    // retrieve the state and socket
```

and gets:

```cs
at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
at Program.ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar) in r:\Temp\LINQPad\aqwfvqfb\query_ettlka.cs:line 102
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

And It's shown even you call `BeginReceive` in `ReceiveCallback`.